# How to filter a string that represents objects

Tags: javascript

Unfortunately, my web services response is returning me a String like this:

```
{"valueStr":"Single"|"valueId":"2019"}
{"valueStr":"Married"|"valueId":"2019"}
{"valueStr":"Divorced"|"valueId":"2020"}
{"valueStr":"Widowed"|"valueId":"2020"}
```

I need to filter out those with the *valueId*. For example, all the 2019 or all the 2020.

The response isn't JSON so I can't parse it, and it's not delimited correctly. So I'm stuck trying something unelegant like this:

```
function parseItemByYear(item){
    // replace all | with ,
    var modifiedObj = item.replace(/\|/g, ',');

    // split into array
    var newArr = modifiedObj.split('}');

    // remove all 
    var newestArr = newArr.map(function(item){item.replace(/^\{/g,'')});

    // JSON.parse the object 
    // var lovObj = JSON.parse(modifiedFilingStatusObj);

    // capture the current tax year
    // replace , with |
    // rebuild the object
    // return the filtered object
    return newestArr;
}
```

But I'm failing where I'm trying to set *newestArr*. My RegEx is wrong. Is my approach too complicated? Is there an easier way that I'm not seeing? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Ask the API / back end team to change it to meaningful Content-Type (if possible), doing everything on front end will bloat your code in long run and don't just agree to agree whatever be the case to resolve things on front end.

Comment: @swapnesh - as a front end developer this should not surprise you - they won't do it.

Comment: Once splitter by lines, just `JSON.parse` the object and grab the `valueId` from it

Comment: Is it all a multi-line string?

Comment: @Akxe - it's one long string

Comment: The data seriously has a pipe instead of a comma? Someone should be fired.

Comment: @Arthur He does split the thing by line and replaces the pipe with coma, then it is parsable as seen is my response bellow. And for the format? It might be a standard for different language... who knows...

Comment: if you replace `\n` with `,` as well and place the string into brackets, you get valid JSON. there are several formats that delimit json streams with newlines, since JSON arrays are hard to stream.

Comment: @Akxe if it was a valid format for something we should have the standard. With it it's easy to create a parsing function (if it's not already exist) but here it look like homemade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is simple and will do the trick.

```js
// Assuming it's single or multiline string
let response = `{"valueStr":"Single"|"valueId":"2019"}
{"valueStr":"Married"|"valueId":"2019"}
{"valueStr":"Divorced"|"valueId":"2020"}
{"valueStr":"Widowed"|"valueId":"2020"}`;

function parseItemByYear(response) {
  // Replace '|' with ','
  response = response.replace(/\|/g, ',');
  
  // Replace '}{' with any whitespace in between to '},{'
  response = response.replace(/}\s?{/g, '},{');
  
  // Make it an array
  let arr = JSON.parse(`[${response}]`);
  
  // Return an array of valueId attribute of all array elements
  return arr.map(item => item.valueId);
}


console.log(parseItemByYear(response));
```

Comment: I have added some comments for clarification, and it will work with single or multi-line strings

Comment: What is this line: var arr = JSON.parse(`[${lov.replace(/}\s{/g, '},{')}]`); . I'm getting a parse error on my JSP page. This is ES6 notation - the ${}?

Comment: ``let arr = JSON.parse(`[${response}]`);`` is equivalent to `var arr = JSON.parse('[' + response + ']');`, Yes it is a string literal with variables

Comment: This line isn't working: response = response.replace(/}\s{/g, '},{');. It's not adding the commas between the objects.

Comment: Then between the objects is not an empty space, could you please `console.log(typeof yourResponseString)` and make sure it's a single string?

Comment: Oh I get what was happening, the objects you received did not have any space in between (Unlike what you posted up in the question), adding `?` after `\s` would make the whitespace optional and would work too :), you could pick any of both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should have split it by new line `\n` and the just use `JSON.parse` as it resembles JSON enough to be parsed.

```js
const response = `{"valueStr":"Single"|"valueId":"2019"}{"valueStr":"Married"|"valueId":"2019"}{"valueStr":"Divorced"|"valueId":"2020"}{"valueStr":"Widowed"|"valueId":"2020"}`;

function parseItemByYear(response){
    // replace all `|` with `,`
    response = response.replace(/\|/g, ',');
    // replace all `}` with `}**BREAK**`
    response = response.replace(/\}/g, '}**BREAK**');

    // split into array
    const newArr = response.split('**BREAK**');
    // Remove last emenet added by regexp
    newArr.pop()

    try {
        return newArr.map(item => JSON.parse(item)/*.valueId*/);
    } catch(e) {
        return new Error('Coud not be parsed');
    }
}

console.log(parseItemByYear(response));
```

Comment: this won't work, it's one long string. Apologies, I should have been clearer

Comment: @fumeng, there you go! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of data handling to get only valueID.
This code is only here to work without JSON (in case of need) but you should consider use standardised format.

```js
const str = `{"valueStr":"Single"|"valueId":"2019"}
{"valueStr":"Married"|"valueId":"2019"}
{"valueStr":"Divorced"|"valueId":"2020"}
{"valueStr":"Widowed"|"valueId":"2020"}`

const results = str.replace(/[\{\}\"]/g, "").split("\n").map(el => el.split("|").map(kv => kv.split(':')).filter(arr => arr[0] === 'valueId')).map(el => el[0][1])

console.log(results)
```

It's always better to use valid stanrd like JSON, use this toJSON function to transform your string into a valid JSON object easier to use.

```js
const str = `{"valueStr":"Single"|"valueId":"2019"}
{"valueStr":"Married"|"valueId":"2019"}
{"valueStr":"Divorced"|"valueId":"2020"}
{"valueStr":"Widowed"|"valueId":"2020"}`

const toJSON = (str) => JSON.parse('[' + (str
                              .replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '')
                              .replace(/\|/g, ",")
                              .replace(/}{/g, "},{")) + ']')
console.log(toJSON(str))

console.log(toJSON(str).map(el => el.valueId))
```